# language accepted by DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[image]

what are the language that the DFA accept ?

so my approach for the first one is : a needs to be 4n+1 for all n>=0, #b%2=0
also i found out there some loops inside the DFA and a:b ratio is 3:1

but how do i write it formally ?  L = {W |.... } ?

second DFA is that the word must end with letter b, there also few loops, so a* can be accepted and folloing with b... so... (a)* b but whats next ?

ty

Comment: Hint for the first: look at $a+2b \bmod{4}$.

Comment: For the second, one way is to decompose the input into runs, and concentrate on the odd runs. There might be a nicer description, though.